# Best tools to perform Performance testing on a web application?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, performance, performance-testing

While performing manual tests, I noticed that some features loading have taken longer to complete. I'm asking about any tools to use to track the performance of my web application (we work with Edge browser the most).

I need to know how if that's caused by the application itself, the servers, or the network connection.

I need your advice based on your experiences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Web application has [frontend and backend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontend_and_backend) and "some features loading more long" may be caused by either slow rendering or slow backend response.

First of all go for your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and see where the page spends the most time. At this stage you can also use frontend performance testing tools like [Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse)

This way you will be able to state whether it is a frontend or a backend issue.

If you have an [APM tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/getting-the-full-application-picture-with-blazemeter-and-apm-integration) in place you can inspect the slow call and trace it down to the underlying problem (slow database call or heavy function, or waiting for a response from an external application or slow network or whatever).

When it comes to "classic" load testing tools - none of them can "tell" you what is the problem, they can only mimic hundreds/thousands of users so you could measure how does your application perform under the load, where the problems start occurring, whether application recovers when the load decreases, etc. There is no "best" tool, there are different tools built in different technologies, some have GUI, some require programming, some can be run in [clustered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster) mode, some are standalone only, some support only 1 [network protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols), some are multiprotocol. In order to come up with a piece of advice we need to know your requirements (and maybe skills), check out [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) article for example investigation and comparison.

Answer (score 1):

There are great open-source load testing tools. There is no greatest one since all of them have pros and cons. I suggest you use [ddosify](https://github.com/ddosify/ddosify) since I'm the co-author and its learning curve is very low. Also, the community support is very active. If you struggle at any point you can put your issue on the [Discord](https://discord.com/invite/9KdnrSUZQg) channel.

Answer (score 0):

Performance testing is an extremely crucial part of the quality assurance model. From analyzing the server capabilities to load testing, performance testing helps to create solutions that are capable of outperforming. However, the only thing that could make the difference is the expertise of your chosen performance testing services provider.

Nevertheless, here is a quick list of performance testing tools that you might want to consider for your upcoming project.

Apache JMeter

Kobiton

LoadNinja

LoadView

WebLoad

You can read more about [performance testing tools](https://www.bugraptors.com/blog/performance-testing-tools) here.

Answer (score 0):

Apache JMeter is known as one of the best free performance testing tools for developers/tester . It is the most popular tool and it is beyond dispute. It supports a 100% Java-scripted desktop application and tests functional performance of web applications, as well. Apache JMeter is available in an open-source format, it is highly accessible for all the software. This tool despite being open-source is extremely versatile.
[1]: https://www.qasource.com/automation-testing-services

Answer (score 0):

Apache JMeter is very easy to use and widely used for Performance testing,